# Spring data neo4j 3.3.1 and Neo4j 2.2.3 transaction builder error

Tags: playframework, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, playframework-2.3

I am currently using Spring Data Neo4j 3.3.0 with Play 2.3.8 using the [tuxburner plugin](https://github.com/tuxBurner/play-neo4jplugin/tree/master) and working remotely with a neo4j 2.1.7 DB.

I saw that the new spring data version supports neo4j 2.2 and i wanted to upgrade to it.
I changed my dependencies to the new versions and am getting the following error:

```
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restNeo4jConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.setGraphDatabaseService(org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService);
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/kernel/TransactionBuilder
```

It seems to be an old issue that should be resolved in 3.3.1 since neo4j 2.2 changed a lot of their internal API and this class no longer exists.

Maybe the way I work with Spring Data is no longer right and needs to be changed.

I've created an example play app that shows the problem:
https://github.com/OlympusTeam/Olympus

Comment: Seems to be one more class that was changed / removed. I'll look into it.

Comment: Have you tried moving from deprecated SpringRestGraphDatabase to SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase?

Comment: Yes. We are currently working with SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase

Comment: @michael is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem while migrating from 2.1, seems to have been fixed in 3.3.2.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/changelog.txt